# Trouble converting list into factor in R

Tags: r

I am having problems creating a boxplot of my data, because one of my variables is in the form of a list. 
I am trying to create a boxplot:

```
boxplot(dist~species, data=out)
```

and received the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dist ~ species, data = out) : 
invalid type (list) for variable 'species'
```

I have been unsuccessful in forcing 'species' into the form of a factor:

```
out[species]<- as.factor(out[[out$species]])
```

and receive the following error:

```
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : invalid subscript type 'list'
```

How can I convert my 'species' column into a factor which I can then use to create a boxplot? Thanks.

EDIT:

```
str(out)
'data.frame':   4570 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ GridRef         : chr  "NT73" "NT80" "NT85" "NT86" ...
 $ pred            : num  154 71 81 85 73 99 113 157 92 85 ...
 $ pred_bin        : int  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ dist            : num  20000 10000 9842 14144 22361 ...
 $ years_since_1990: chr  "21" "16" "21" "20" ...
 $ species         :List of 4570
..$ : chr "C.splendens"
..$ : chr "C.splendens"
..$ : chr "C.splendens"
.. [list output truncated]
```

Comment: we need to see at least `str(out)` in order to be able to help.

Comment: Edited to add str(out). Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's hard to imagine how you got the data into this form in the first place, but it looks like

```
out <- transform(out,species=unlist(species))
```

should solve your problem.

```
set.seed(101)
f <- as.list(sample(letters[1:5],replace=TRUE,size=100))
## need I() to make a wonky data frame ...
d <- data.frame(y=runif(100),f=I(f))
## 'data.frame':    100 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ y: num  0.125 0.0233 0.3919 0.8596 0.7183 ...
##  $ f:List of 100
##   ..$ : chr "b"
##   ..$ : chr "a"
boxplot(y~f,data=d)  ## invalid type (list) ...
d2 <- transform(d,f=unlist(f))
boxplot(y~f,data=d2)
```